# Error on npm run build with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I built a small react app using the create-react-app boiler plate. When serving the content with `npm run` everything works fine.

But now I tried running the builder for the first time because I am at a point where I would like to show a demo. I tried running `npm run build` but it errors out. Here is the npm log:

`0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]
2 info using npm@3.3.12
3 info using node@v5.1.1
4 verbose config Skipping project config: /Users/falks/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
5 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/falks/package.json'
5 verbose stack     at Error (native)
6 verbose cwd /Users/falks
7 error Darwin 15.6.0
8 error argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
9 error node v5.1.1
10 error npm  v3.3.12
11 error path /Users/falks/package.json
12 error code ENOENT
13 error errno -2
14 error syscall open
15 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/falks/package.json'
15 error enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
15 error enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
16 verbose exit [ -2, true ]`

It appears that it is looking for a package.json outside of my development folder? Any hint how to get the builder to run?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the command in the application directory?

Comment: Yes,  same directory I run start and do all my git stuff from.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be in the wrong folder because of this line in your error

`ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/falks/package.json'`

You need to run that command from the same folder that the package.json file is - typically the root folder of your project... it looks like you are trying to run it from your home folder.

-- edited: lol, why did I respond to a question that is over a year old and Dan Abramov already answered - please ignore me